# jupyter can't find caffe

Tags: ipython, caffe, jupyter-notebook

It might be a simple question.

I can't call `caffe` from `jupyter notebook`. I have `python 2.7.6` and `ipython 5.0.0` installed. Both can import `caffe`. And `$PYTHONPATH` has contained `/path/to/caffe/python`.
`Jupyter` itself is 4.2.1.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-9-1cca3aa1f8c5> in <module>()
----> 1 import caffe

ImportError: No module named caffe
```

What might be the problem?

Comment: Can you share the stack trace?

Comment: I added it in the question

Comment: Have you tried printing the pythonpath within the notebook?

Comment: Can you tell me please how to do that? Or did you mean `print (sys.path)`?

Comment: Yeah, the output of ``sys.path`` would be nice.

Answer (score 2):

Try to add this into your header

```
sys.path.append('YOUR PATH TO CAFFE')
```